# How to get number of rows that COULD have been affected by an UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Getting the number of rows affected by a MySQL update is one thing, but how do I get the number of matching rows for an UPDATE query? Otherwise put, the number of rows that COULD have been affected by the update query, even if the data I'm trying to update the rows with is identical to the data already contained within them? Because in this specific case, the DB will not overwrite the data with, so the number of affected rows is 0.
Is there some PDO method that helps, similar to `PDOStatement::rowCount()` ?
I also want to avoid a secondary SQL statement, otherwise the question is pointless.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how that's relevant?

Comment: Every question is relevant, because answer can be different depends on the details.

Comment: I need to throw a specific exception when there are no rows matching my query, testing the number of affected rows. Seeing how that returns 0 by default when I try to update the rows with the same information that already exists within them, my code used to throw an incorrect exception when that happened. But I've managed to find the solution without having to resort to a secondary query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to avoid extra queries if possible and fortunately, a colleague of mine pointed out that I can give the PDO instance a particular MySQL driver option that forces the `rowCount` method to return the number of matches related to the query, instead of the number of affected rows, like so:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true    // forces the rowCount() method to return the number of matching rows, not the number of affected rows
);   
$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `count()` in a `select` clause for that:

If your `update` statement would be

```
update your_table
set some_column = 'hello'
where id = 1
```

Then you could select the affected rows count like this

```
select count(*) as affected_rows
from your_table
where id = 1
```

Comment: This would be the correct query:
select count(*) as affected_rows from your_table where id = 1 and some_column != 'hello';

Comment: Actually, no it wouldn't.

Comment: For a table ``x`` like this: 

    a  b
    1  1
if you do 'select count(*) from x where a=1' will return 1. While the query 'update x set b=1 where a=1 will update 0 rows'.
Hence, what you need to do is 'select count(*) from x where a=1 and b!= 1'.

Comment: You are actually right for MySQL. Didn't know that. In MSSQL the rows get affected if even or not.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a secondary query, if possible. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way:

```
mysql_query('begin');
mysql_query('update ...');
mysql_affected_rows();
mysql_query('rollback');
```

select count(*) is a better thing to do for simple queries. But that won't get correct results in case you are updating multiple tables with joins.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_query`

Comment: this answer misses the point of the question. It always worth to read not only title but question body too

Answer (score -2):

Add the column update_time in model.Whenever update model.Automatically save updated time in that field.
And
How about querying like this

```
SELECT * from
table_name
WHERE 'updated_time=12:05:23'
```